# Zip file download

Tags: node.js, http-headers

I have something like that:

```
function DownLoadZip(response){
    console.log(response.zipFile); // result of console log - example.zip
    res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
            'Content-Length': stat.size
        });
};
```

Question: How can I give to client completed zip file. This file comes with response. Maybe I forgot some headers or that is something else. Any ideas?
Thanks for attention and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps somebody!
I have forgotten type:

```
res.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `response.zipFile` is a path:
`fs.createReadStream(response.zipFile).pipe(res);`

If `response` is a stream:
`response.pipe(res);`

Comment: I haven't this file on my local machine or on server. That file comes from another place with response.